# Flutter can't initialize BLoC provider in the didChangeDependencies()

Tags: flutter, dart

Good morning, In my Flutter journal project I have HomeBlocProvider and HomeBloc.
In the Home page I am initializing the HomeBloc in the didChangeDependencies() function but somehow it doesn't initialize

In the build() I am declaring the variable
`HomeBloc? _homeBloc;`

and this is the didChangeDependencies()

```
    @override
    void didChangeDependencies() {
      super.didChangeDependencies();
      _homeBloc = HomeBlocProvider.of(context).homeBloc;
    }
```

The body property of the Scaffold() is StreamBuilder() and the stream property of it I am listening to the `_homeBloc!.listJournal`

When I run the project I got this error
`Exception caught by widgets library`
`The following _CastError was thrown building Home(dirty, state: _HomeState#ada70):`
`Null check operator used on a null value`

So it seems like the homeBloc still null

This is the code of the HomeBlocProvider

```
class HomeBlocProvider extends InheritedWidget {
  const HomeBlocProvider({Key? key, required Widget child, this.homeBloc, this.uid}) : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(HomeBlocProvider oldWidget) => homeBloc != oldWidget.homeBloc;

  static HomeBlocProvider of(BuildContext context) {
    return (context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<HomeBlocProvider>() as HomeBlocProvider);
  }

  final HomeBloc? homeBloc;
  final String? uid;
}
```

I tried to print a string in the didChangeDependecies() and nothing printed so it seems that it doesn't even execute the function

Comment: Are you using flutter_bloc?

Comment: @pixel Because I am using it to listen to a property in it in the StreamBuilder in the body

Comment: But why do you want to make a new instance of the bloc you have in the provider. You have only one goal of putting that bloc in the provider to share the same instance with all other files, and here making a new instance is not aligning on that goal. You just can use that bloc like this `HomeBlocProvider.of(context).homeBloc`. And about the issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```dart
  late HomeBloc _homeBloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _homeBloc = HomeBlocProvider.of(context).homeBloc;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  }
```

Comment: LateInitializationError: Local '_homeBloc' has not been initialized.

Comment: That means i guess there's some exception being thrown when you access `HomeBlocProvider.of(context).homeBloc`

Answer (score 0):

The `didChangeDependencies()` method is called when the dependencies of the widget change, which can happen during the widget's lifecycle. However, it's not guaranteed to be called every time the widget is rebuilt.

In your case, the `HomeBloc` initialization logic should be placed in the `initState()` method instead of `didChangeDependencies()`. The `initState()` method is called exactly once when the widget is inserted into the widget tree.

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  _homeBloc = HomeBlocProvider.of(context).homeBloc;
}
```

Also, make sure that `HomeBloc` is initialized and provided properly to widget tree.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, by declaring the object and then triggering the function in 'init' state or didChangeDependencies() -

```
class _CheckoutViewState extends State<CheckoutView> {
  final _checkoutBloc = CheckoutBloc();

  CartBloc? cartBloc;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkoutBloc.add(CheckoutInitialEvent());
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _checkoutBloc.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<CheckoutBloc, CheckoutState>(
      bloc: _checkoutBloc,
      listenWhen: (previous, current) => current is CheckoutActionState,
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is CheckoutSuccessState) {
          context.router.popAndPush(const OrderHistoryViewRoute());
        } else if (state is CheckoutFailedState) {
          log('failed');
        }
      },
      buildWhen: (previous, current) => current is! CheckoutActionState,
      builder: (context, state) {
        return switch (state) {
          CheckoutLoadingState() => const LoadingWidget(),
          CheckoutLoadedState(:final localOrderCartModel) =>
            BuildCheckoutLoaded(
              localOrderCartModel: localOrderCartModel,
              cartBloc: cartBloc,
              checkoutBloc: _checkoutBloc,
            ),
          // CheckoutErrorState() => const ErrorView(),
          (_) => const SizedBox.shrink(), //default condition
        };
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the bloc class -

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:shineoak/model/local_order_cart_model/local_order_cart_model.dart';
import 'package:shineoak/resources/helper/import.dart';
part 'checkout_event.dart';
part 'checkout_state.dart';

class CheckoutBloc extends Bloc<CheckoutEvent, CheckoutState> {
  final LocalOrderRepository _localOrderRepository = LocalOrderRepository();

  CheckoutBloc() : super(CheckoutInitial()) {
    on<CheckoutEvent>(_mapEventToState);
  }

  Future<void> _mapEventToState(
      CheckoutEvent event, Emitter<CheckoutState> emit) async {
    if (event is CheckoutInitialEvent) {
      try {
        emit(CheckoutLoadingState());
       //execute everything after the
      } catch (e) {
        emit(CheckoutErrorState());
      }
    } else if (event is SwipeToPayEvent) {
      emit(CheckoutLoadingState());
      // emit(stateToReturn);

    }
  }
}
```